# ESLint/Prettier/Airbnb : Do I set them up again for each project?

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier, eslint-config-airbnb

I have just finished setting up Eslint/prettier/airbnb by watching an online tutorial but what I don't understand is that when I start a new project, will I need to repeat the same processes* again? I wish there was a way to integrate it to VSCode so it starts automatically when I ran the code for any project.

*below is what I meant by processes:

```
npm i -D eslint prettier eslint-plugin-prettier eslint-config-prettier eslint-plugin-node eslint-config-node
npx install-peerdeps --dev eslint-config-airbnb
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a template project to avoid having to do that, or you could just copy `package.json` to you new project, edit it a bit and run `npm install`

Comment: Or you could talk a look at https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/eslint-config-auto

Comment: Which part will need to be edited? Isn't package.json all I need?